# My Azure Website has an odd "HTTP success" pattern in the (Monitor) portal

Tags: http, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a website hosted in Azure Websites as a *Basic* tier website.
I'm currently in the development stage, yet the site is live and accessible by the outside world (at least at a basic level), so I wanted to better understand the monitoring features in the Azure management portal.

When I looked at the monitoring tab inside the portal, I see an odd pattern for `HTTP success`. Looking at the past *60 minutes* (which I personally have not been active on), the `HTTP successes` are very cyclic, with **80** connections, then **0**, then **40**, then **0**, then repeat.

[image: Azure portal - Monitor]

Does anyone have any pointers how I can figure out what the **80** and **40** connections are. I certainly don't have any timed events in my code, so there shouldn't be any calls being made unless a person is actually hitting the site.

**UPDATE:**

I setup a staging server and blocked all incoming traffic except my own IP. So the same code running, just without access from the outside world. And the `HTTP success` appears only when I hit the server myself (as expected). This suggests that my site is being hit by an outside bot maybe? **Does anyone know how to protect against this?** Or at least diagnose if the requests are not legitimate, etc?

Comment: Are you running any web tests or monitoring of any kind?

Comment: No web tests or additional monitoring. Only what is defaulted in setting up an Azure website.

Comment: @Brett are you sure you don't have web endpoint status set up for this host? Check the dashboard tab of the azure website and check. If this is enabled it would explain why the requests are coming form microsoft.

Comment: Cleaned my answer up and added some details. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it's this setting that causes the traffic:

> Always On. By default, websites are unloaded if they are idle for some period of time. This lets the system conserve resources. In Basic or Standard mode, you can enable Always On to keep the site loaded all the time. If your site runs continuous web jobs, you should enable Always On, or the web jobs may not run reliably

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/

It's just a keep alive to avoid cold starts every time you or someone else visit your site.

**[Here's](http://wp.sjkp.dk/windows-azure-websites-and-cloud-services-slow-on-first-request/) another reference that describes this behavior:**

> What the always-on feature does is simply ping your site every now and
>   then, to keep the application pool up and running.

**And [Scott Gu says](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2014/01/16/windows-azure-staging-publishing-support-for-web-sites-monitoring-improvements-hyper-v-recovery-manager-ga-and-pci-compliance.aspx%20%22%22Scott%20Gu%20says%20the%20following:):**

> One of the other useful Web Site features that we are introducing
>   today is a feature we call “Always On”. When Always On is enabled on a
>   site, Windows Azure will automatically ping your Web Site regularly to
>   ensure that the Web Site is always active and in a warm/running state.
>   This is useful to ensure that a site is always responsive (and that
>   the app domain or worker process has not paged out due to lack of
>   external HTTP requests).

**About the traffic in general**: First of all, the requests could really only come from Microsoft, since any traffic pattern like this will quickly be automatically detected and blocked when using Azure Websites - you cannot set up a keep alive like this yourself. Second, no modern bot whatsoever would regularily ping a specific page with that kind of regularity since it's all to obvious. Any modern datacenter security appliance would catch that kind of traffic and block/ignore/nullroute it.

**As for your question regarding protection and security:** Microsoft cannot protect your code from yourself. However, everything at the perimeter is managed and handled by Microsoft. That's one of the USP features of Azure - Firewall, Load Balancing, Spoofing, Anti-bot and DDOS protection etc. There will of course always be security concerns regarding any publicly exposed service but you can stay focused on your application while Microsoft manages the rest.

When running Azure Websites, you're in the hands of Microsoft regarding security outside of your application scope. That's a great thing, but if you really like to be able to use other security measures you'll have to set up a virtual machine instead and run your site from there.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to first understand what are these requests. Enable web server logging for the website on Azure Management portal and download IIS logs for your website after seeing this pattern. Then check those to understand the URL, client ip addresses   for the requests and user agent field to identify if the requests are really from search bots. Based on the observation, you can either disable some IP statically, use dynamic ip restrictions or configure URLREWRITE to block requests with specific patterns in request or request headers

EDIT 
This is how you can block search bots - http://moz.com/ugc/blocking-bots-based-on-useragent

You can configure the URLREWRITE locally on an IIS server in the way described in the above article and then copy the configuration generated in the web.config or connect to the azure website directly using IIS manager as described in http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/02/28/remote-administration-of-windows-azure-websites-using-iis-manager/ and configure urlrewrite rule

Comment: I was able to look at the logs like you suggested. There are TWO IP addresses that are hitting my homepage. Using reverse IP lookups, I see that BOTH IPs are coming from Microsoft?!?!? What could that possibly be about? Why would hit my site this often and this systematically?

Also, the useragent string for all the requests is: Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+9.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+Trident/5.0)